# Looking for title of movie that shows asteroid flying towards earth and hitting USA in the end

Tags: story-identification, movie, tv

Large asteroid flying towards Earth and military try to destroy it and fail.
1 phrase I remember very good.

President is got that comet or asteroid is going to hit america and if they destroy it near orbit, it would
break up and shower all over the planet and president says something like:

''Then America has to take a hit for the entire world''

Next scene - a journalist is reporting from emptied city saying ''we are having a last look at the cities before we say goodbye to them'' Journalist was female and wearing yellow coat.

Next scene - meteorite/comet hits with big flash. An old man and his grandsoon hide in the basement and it can be seen
as whole house is blown away and then basement planks fly away.

Final scene - grandson runs away and needs to be rescured from a huge crater created by the hit.

I have rented out all movies i could find - about 3-4, but none of them matched what I saw here.
I think it is one of those low budget TV Movies.
May be SyFy

Comment: When did you see this?  Where?

Comment: I would say Deep Impact but the house with the man and the kid don't match. There is this website, https://vissiniti.com/a-to-z-list/?amp  I found several movies that I had seen many years ago with meteors and asteroids. Maybe the tittles and years might make you remember witch movie it might be.

Comment: I remember the last half of the movie, but the first half isn't exactly that way. They initially shoot it down using laser of some kind, after which they start celebrating. A father is telling his daughter (who worked on destroying it) that she's the person who saved the most lives on Earth (save for Superman). But one guy realises that they only broke the asteroid into tinier bits, which are still coming toward Earth.

Comment: The reference to female journalist in yellow made me think of [Deep Impact](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0120647/?ref_=nv_sr_srsg_0) in which Tea Leoni plays a journalist trying to find the meaning of ELE and more-or-less stumbling upon a complex and somewhat secretive government plan to save American civilization from an "extinction-level event" comet/asteroid impact by bunkering a selected slice of the population.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the made-for-TV movie [*Asteroid*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0118261/) (1997). The [synopsis on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asteroid_(film)) mentions searching a crater for a lost relative and a kid and his granddad hiding out in a basement.

> After searching the ruined city, she finally locates Elliot in a large impact crater. Jack arrives to help in a helicopter. He rescues Elliot and the four return to base where they watch the comet pass by Earth, and are relieved it won't return to cause trouble for another 4,000 years.

Comment: As someone who recognises the movie from the question, I'm 99% sure that this is the correct movie. I remember they broke the asteroid by shooting laser of some kind at it. The kid and the senior guy hiding in the basement, where the guy realises the small window isn't closed. As he approaches to close it, the asteroid touches down and knocks him back. And the ending where the kid is somehow stuck on a broken apartment building, falling toward the burning center of the crater.

Comment: @Clockwork - I've flicked through an online copy and I can't find the President's line about taking one for the team, nor the yellow-jacketed reporter.

Comment: Thank You Very Much. That is correct one.
I don't know where to mark it as answered.
May Moderator would help and show me where to mark as answered